# Participant trash others replies from their own topic in bbpress

Tags: php, wordpress, bbpress

I was looking for this for too long but didn't find any.

**How to allow Participant to trash others replies only from their own topics?**

Please help!

**Note:** I've used **User Role Editor** and selected `delete_others_replies` but it allows Participant to trash replies from other topics also. I only want to trash form their own topics only.